# XML parsing error when trying to read node values of XML

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2014

I have a XML file(TestArticles.xml), which I need to import into SQL SERVER 2014 and read the data from the various nodes and insert it into few other tables in the same database.

**TestArticles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Articles>
<sv:node sv:name="test1"
    xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
      <sv:value>mgnl:tax-article</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:createdBy" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>system</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
</sv:node>
<sv:node sv:name="test2"
    xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
      <sv:value>mgnl:tax-article</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:createdBy" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>admin</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
</sv:node>  
</Articles>
```

I tried the following steps:

1. Import XML data from an XML file into SQL Server table using the OPENROWSET function

---

```
USE DataMigration

GO


CREATE TABLE ArticlesXML
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
ArticlesXMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)


INSERT INTO ArticlesXML(ArticlesXMLData, LoadedDateTime)
SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() 
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Temp\articles.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;


SELECT * FROM ArticlesXML
```

---

2. Parsing the XML data using the OPENXML function

---

```
USE DataMigration

GO

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = ArticlesXMLData FROM ArticlesXML

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT ArticleName
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Articles/sv:node')
WITH 
(
   ArticleName [varchar](100) '@sv:name'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc

GO
```

On executing the above query, I am getting the below mentioned error:

> Msg 6603, Level 16, State 2, Line 14
>   XML parsing error: Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'sv'.

I want to fetch the following from the TestArticles.xml

1. sv:name from each sv:node
2. sv:value from each sv:property node within the sv:node

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Btw: `FROM OPENXML` with the SPs to call before and after is absolutely outdated and should not be used any more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query you can read all data within your XML:

```
CREATE TABLE ArticlesXML
(
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
ArticlesXMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT ArticlesXML ON;
INSERT INTO ArticlesXML(Id,ArticlesXMLData,LoadedDateTime) VALUES
(1,
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Articles>
<sv:node sv:name="test1"
    xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
      <sv:value>mgnl:tax-article</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:createdBy" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>system</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
</sv:node>
<sv:node sv:name="test2"
    xmlns:sv="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:primaryType" sv:type="Name">
      <sv:value>mgnl:tax-article</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
    <sv:property sv:name="jcr:createdBy" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>admin</sv:value>
    </sv:property>
</sv:node>  
</Articles>',GETDATE());
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ArticlesXML OFF;

WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0' AS sv
                  ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
SELECT Id
      ,Article.value('@sv:name','varchar(max)') AS ArticleName
      ,Property.value('@sv:name','varchar(max)') AS PropertyName
      ,Property.value('@sv:type','varchar(max)') AS PropertyType
      ,Property.value('sv:value[1]','varchar(max)') AS PropertyValue
      ,LoadedDateTime
FROM ArticlesXML
CROSS APPLY ArticlesXML.ArticlesXMLData.nodes('/Articles/sv:node') A(Article)
CROSS APPLY A.Article.nodes('sv:property') AS B(Property);
--CleanUp
--DROP TABLE ArticlesXML;
```

The Result

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| Id | ArticleName | PropertyName    | PropertyType | PropertyValue    | LoadedDateTime          |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test1       | jcr:primaryType | Name         | mgnl:tax-article | 2016-03-31 13:52:26.753 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test1       | jcr:createdBy   | String       | system           | 2016-03-31 13:52:26.753 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test2       | jcr:primaryType | Name         | mgnl:tax-article | 2016-03-31 13:52:26.753 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test2       | jcr:createdBy   | String       | admin            | 2016-03-31 13:52:26.753 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
```

If you want to query this somehow (filter, aggregation...) you have several chances:

- put the result into a temp table and use this however you like
- same with a declared table variable
- Surround and use it as CTE

(This looks like this)

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0' AS sv
                  ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
,TableDataCTE AS
(
    SELECT Id
          ,Article.value('@sv:name','varchar(max)') AS ArticleName
          ,Property.value('@sv:name','varchar(max)') AS PropertyName
          ,Property.value('@sv:type','varchar(max)') AS PropertyType
          ,Property.value('sv:value[1]','varchar(max)') AS PropertyValue
          ,LoadedDateTime
    FROM ArticlesXML
    CROSS APPLY ArticlesXML.ArticlesXMLData.nodes('/Articles/sv:node') A(Article)
    CROSS APPLY A.Article.nodes('sv:property') AS B(Property)
)
SELECT * FROM TableDataCTE;
WHERE ...
```

- or you might use XQuery predicats ( e.g. `.nodes('/Articles/sv:node[sv:name="test1"]')` )

### EDIT The enhanced SELECT to reflect your need to read multi-value properties according to the sampe you gave in your comment:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0' AS sv
                  ,'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' AS xsi)
SELECT Id
      ,Article.value('@sv:name','varchar(max)') AS ArticleName
      ,Property.value('@sv:name','varchar(max)') AS PropertyName
      ,Property.value('@sv:type','varchar(max)') AS PropertyType
      ,Value.value('.','varchar(max)') AS PropertyValue
      ,LoadedDateTime
FROM ArticlesXML
CROSS APPLY ArticlesXML.ArticlesXMLData.nodes('/Articles/sv:node') A(Article)
CROSS APPLY A.Article.nodes('sv:property') AS B(Property)
CROSS APPLY B.Property.nodes('sv:value') AS C(Value);
```

The result:

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| Id | ArticleName | PropertyName    | PropertyType | PropertyValue    | LoadedDateTime          |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test1       | jcr:primaryType | Name         | mgnl:tax-article | 2016-03-31 20:30:27.240 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test1       | jcr:createdBy   | String       | system           | 2016-03-31 20:30:27.240 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test2       | jcr:primaryType | Name         | mgnl:tax-article | 2016-03-31 20:30:27.240 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test2       | jcr:createdBy   | String       | admin            | 2016-03-31 20:30:27.240 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test3       | jcr:createdBy   | String       | admin1           | 2016-03-31 20:30:27.240 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test3       | jcr:createdBy   | String       | admin2           | 2016-03-31 20:30:27.240 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test3       | jcr:createdBy   | String       | admin3           | 2016-03-31 20:30:27.240 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test3       | jcr:createdBy   | String       | admin4           | 2016-03-31 20:30:27.240 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test3       | jcr:createdBy   | String       | admin5           | 2016-03-31 20:30:27.240 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
| 1  | test3       | jcr:createdBy   | String       | admin6           | 2016-03-31 20:30:27.240 |
+----+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------------+-------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the help. It really helped me :). I need one more small help from you. If I have one of the node in this pattern : <sv:property sv:name="jcr:createdBy" sv:type="String">
      <sv:value>admin1</sv:value>
   <sv:value>admin2</sv:value>
   <sv:value>admin3</sv:value>
   <sv:value>admin4</sv:value>
   <sv:value>admin5</sv:value>
   <sv:value>admin6</sv:value>
    </sv:property>                                                                                                       then in that case Property.value('sv:value[1]','varchar(max)') AS PropertyValue is not working for me.

Comment: In short, I need all the values : admin1,admin2,admin3,admin4,admin5. SELECT Id,     
      Property.value('sv:value[1]','varchar(max)') AS PropertyValue
      ,LoadedDateTime
FROM ArticlesXML
CROSS APPLY ArticlesXML.ArticlesXMLData.nodes('/Articles/sv:node') A(Article)
CROSS APPLY A.Article.nodes('sv:property') AS B(Property);                         the above query is not working here.Can you please help me.

Comment: Super cool. You are awesome :). Thanks a ton for the help. It really helped me to resolve my issue :). Thanks once again a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to explicitly define the prefix first, for example, using [`WITH XMLNAMESPACES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177400.aspx) and XQuery :

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.jcp.org/jcr/sv/1.0' as sv)
SELECT c.value('@sv:name', 'varchar(100)') As Name
FROM ArticlesXML a
    CROSS APPLY ArticlesXMLData.nodes('Articles/sv:node') t(c)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. But here I want to read sv:value node value within the sv:property tag based on the sv:name in the where condition. For example  sv:value= 3fe558bd-d3aa-4c27-a975-f5ee8abc497f where sv:name="jcr:uuid"